# Using hook_menu in a custom module, how do you add a menu item to more than one menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: routes, hooks

I am working with Drupal 7.  I have created a custom module that supplies several menu items using hook_menu.  I am adding one of these menu items to the main menu:

```
$items['my-chapter'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Chapter',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_my_chapter',
    'file' => 'includes/pages.inc',
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'weight' => '110',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
```

Adding the menu item to the main menu works fine using this code.  But I have a secondary menu that also needs this link.  Is there a way to add it to another menu in addition to the main menu I'm already adding it to?  Adding another $items['my-chapter'] will obviously just overwrite the previous one and the 'menu_name' only takes a single string.

Can anyone shed some light on how/if this can be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for [`menu_link_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) as adding the `menu_name` in `hook_menu()` just puts this callback in that menu instead of defaulting it into the `navigation` menu.  So, after creating it above, with or without the `menu_name`, you should be able to add it to any other menu(s) with [`menu_link_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the menu_link_save() function.  This reads like it should work, I'm just not sure of an appropriate place to call this in my module.  Setting up this menu should be a one time event.  Adding this duplicate link I need should only happen after the menu links are created and definitely not every time the module is in play. There is no admin to this module that would toggle this on and off firing the function on an isolated event.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose you could put it inside a `menu_alter()` although it might not really belong there, but at least it would only be called on menu rebuilds, and if you surrounded it with some variable_get()/variable_set() logic, it might only be called once.  Or maybe when you are done with development, you could put it in your MODULE.install?

Comment: I don't think the MODULE.install would be the best place to put it as the link has to be defined first, and that happens after `hook_install()` I believe.  So I went with your first supposition and appropriated the `hook_menu_alter()`.  As you pointed out, it might not really belong there and does feel a little hackish using it for not quite what it was intended, but in the absence of any other thoughts on the matter, it does work.  I do a check for the entry in the DB, and if the entry doesn't exist I use `menu_link_save()` to add it.  It should only fire when the menus are rebuilt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another entry, such as the following one.

```
$items['my-chapter-2'] = array(
  'title' => 'My Chapter',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_my_chapter',
  'file' => 'includes/pages.inc',
  'menu_name' => $menu_name,
  'weight' => '110',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Replace `$menu_name` with the name of the menu where the menu item should appear.

Drupal just needs to know the page callback to call, and the users just see the menu title. In this way, you can have two menu items showing the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `hook_enable()` would be a more appropriate place for using `menu_link_save()` as it is only fired once and after the `.module` file is fully loaded, so your custom menu item would already be in place. You will also need to add `'customized' => 1,` to your menu link array otherwise it wont be added. [ref.](https://api.drupal.org/comment/54898#comment-54898). Don't forget to the remove the menu link in `hook_disable()`. They should both be placed in the `.install` file of your module.

[hook_enable()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7)